# Android Studio project has stopped

Tags: android

I clicked on the button number in the emulator, the app has stopped. But when I wrote the first time code and run it. There is no problem at all

Java Code :

```
EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
int sum = num1 + num2;
t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
```

Comment: please share your code and logcat

Comment: What you have entered in that edittexts? Is that numbers or any other alphabetic characters?

Comment: Safer and Best way to do is t1.setText(""+sum);